# Mutliplr print functionality return inconsistent data , on changing $timeout value

Tags: angularjs, printing

I want to print a multiple barcode slip, each will have different barcode.

Using a print service to print the div content,

```
(function() {
 'use strict';
 angular.module('app.services')
  .factory('PrintService', PrintService);

 PrintService.$inject = [];

 function PrintService() {
  var service = {
   printElement: printElement
  };

  return service;



  function printElement(elem) {

   var printSection = document.getElementById('printSection');

   // if there is no printing section, create one
   if (!printSection) {
    printSection = document.createElement('div');
    printSection.id = 'printSection';
    document.body.appendChild(printSection);
   }
   var elemToPrint = document.getElementById(elem);
   // clones the element you want to print
   var domClone = elemToPrint.cloneNode(true);
   printSection.innerHTML = '';
   printSection.appendChild(domClone);
   window.print();
   window.onafterprint = function() {
       printSection.innerHTML = '';
   }
  };

 }
})();
```

Using this print service, will print the slip. Slip data    will bind.

```
var userServicePromise =   UserService.printBarCodes(sampleId);
                 userServicePromise.then(function(response) {
                    if (response != null && response.data != null && response.data.result != null) {

                    response.data.result.forEach(function(entry) {
                    /* $timeout(function() {
                        vm.barCodeImage = angular.copy(entry);
                      }, 0);*/
                        //vm.testName = item.testMast.testName.slice(0, 3);
                         vm.barCodeImage = angular.copy(entry);
                          $timeout(function() {
                             PrintService.printElement("printThisElement");
                         }, 1);
                        }); 
                     } else {
                         toaster.error(response.data.message);
                     }
                 });
```

This is the html which will be printed eventually, using DOM element id for printing.

```
 <div id="printThisElement" class="onlyprint" >
  <table>
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ ctrl.instCode }}</td>
        <td align="center">{{ ctrl.date  | dateDisplayFilter}}  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="2" align="center"> <img ng-src="data:image/JPEG;base64,{{ctrl.barCodeImage}}"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="2" align="center">{{ ctrl.user.name }} </td>
    </tr>
        <tr> 
        <td >Reg Id: {{ ctrl.regIdLookup }}</td>
        <td align="center">{{ ctrl.testName }}</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
   </div>
```

Expected out put is three slips with different barcode:
 7865
 7866
 7867

Output is three slips with same barcode 
 7865
 7865
 7865
 some times,
 7866
 7866
 7866

On changing the $timeout(function() value output be like
 7865
 7865
 7866

what can be the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Never ever modify the DOM from inside a service, that's just totally against the whole way Angular works. What you should do instead is create a model of the data (and it's quite alright to create that in the service) and use Angular's templates to render that model in the page.

The reason your code doesn't work is that you are trying to re-use `vm.barCodeImage` for different images on the page. Angular tracks the changes and will redraw existing parts of the page. That is why you get the same barcode repeated: the different copies each use the same model so they will be the same.

A simple solution is to create an array of`vm.barCodeImages` and then just render them in an `ng-repeat` loop. A better way might be to create a `myBarcode` directive which uses `UserService.printBarCodes` to create one barcode in an isolated scope and then your template will look shorter and tidier.

Comment: UserService.printBarCodes creates more than one bar code. Also, if I loop thru ng- repeat, Do I need to modify print service completely ?

Comment: Need to display in three different page three different prints.